# Parse emailVerified boolean not resolving from User object

Tags: parse-platform, android-studio

I am trying to make sure user's email has been verified prior to logging in to my app via Parse. For some reason, the `emailVerified` boolean that should be part of the Parse User object is not resolving. I am getting `error: cannot find symbol variable emailVerified`. What am I doing wrong here?

```
/* send data to Parse.com for verification */
    ParseUser.logInInBackground(usernametxt, passwordtxt,
        new LogInCallback() {
            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                            if (user != null) {
                                    if(user.emailVerified == true) {
                                    /* if user exists and is authenticated, notify user */
                                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                "Successfully Logged In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                                        toast.show();

                                        finish();
                                    }
                                }
```

Comment: What about `user.getBoolean("emailVerified");`?

Comment: Yes, that did it! They really should add this to their documentation. How did you find this? I would like some kind of reference in case I run into similar problems.

Comment: Ah it is actually stated in the guide clearly. You must have missed it https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-retrieving